# Ruby + Memcached? Which Library to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, memcached

I am not a Ruby guy. I am a python guy. Though now I have to use Ruby (not rails) which needs to store some keyvalue pairs in memcached.  Which library to use (if its available in debian, thats better) ? Im a little bewildered, some look obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know which Gem to use that [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is a good place to start. Browser your category and pick a Gem that is popular and under maintenance.

At the moment it seems like [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) is most popular library.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not picky about using memcached, I'd suggest using [Redis](http://redis.io/) for key-value storage in memory.

If you definitely need memcached, the [gem of that name](https://rubygems.org/gems/memcached) was [updated on May 8](https://github.com/evan/memcached). Hardly obsolete.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was looking at https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients#Ruby, and most of the links are 404s now.

Comment: Also, only ruby-memcache-client is in Debian, which says "deprecated as of August 2010. "

Comment: You should install Ruby libraries using the [RubyGems package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems). If you've installed a recent version of Ruby, RubyGems will already be installed. You can install the memcached gem using `gem install memcached`.

Comment: Redis is a great key-value storage, but definitiv not a caching solution. A storage system for caching should deleted old (rarely used) keys when it runs out of memory. Redis just stops working, if it runs out of memory...

Comment: Yes, I want things to expire from it.

Answer (score 0):

The gem that I've always seen recommended when it comes to Ruby + Memcached is [dalii](https://rubygems.org/gems/dalli).